# Styles.Render and Scripts.Render does not render properly in different areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have at least 3 areas in my mvc project.
All css and js files are located in Css folder and JS folder respectively at the root `"~/css/" ~/js/`

I register the bundle inside Global.asax file like this:

```
        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new StyleBundle(CssVirtualPath("mastercss"))
            .Include(Css("bootstrap.min.css"), new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
            .Include(Css("bootstrap-responsive.min.css"), new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
            .Include(Css("normalize.css"), new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
            .Include(Css("media.css"), new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
            .Include(Css("jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css"), new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
            .Include(Css("icons.css"), new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
            .Include(Css("MetroJs.css"), new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
            );  

    private static string CssVirtualPath(string filename)
    {
        return string.Format("~/bundle/css/{0}", RemoveSpecialChars(filename));
    }  

    private static string Css(string filename)
    {
        filename = RemoveSpecialChars(filename);
        return string.Format("~/css/{0}", filename);
    }  

    private static string RemoveSpecialChars(string value)
    {
        return value.Replace("/", "").Replace(@"\", "").Replace("~", "");
    }
```

At Area 1/Login page, I'm calling the bundle like this:

```
@Styles.Render("bundle/css/mastercss")
```

Equivalent on page source is:

```
<link href="/bundle/css/mastercss" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

And it works fine. But after I logged in, the profile page (view) rendering fails:
Area 1/User
Same code was used:

```
@Styles.Render("bundle/css/mastercss")
```

Equivalent on page source is:

```
<link href="/Area1/User/bundle/css/mastercss" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

And it fails to load... What should I do? I've been looking for answers, but found no luck.